# How to enlarge block in Ghidra's Function Graph View?

Tags: ghidra

I can't seem to figure out how to do such a trivial task: Basically, how can I enlarge a block in Ghidra's Function Graph View so that I can see all of the instructions (instead of **...**).

There does not seem to be an enlarge option when I hover my mouse over the edge of the block.

The version I am using is 9.1.2

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it from the menu of this window.

Click on this icon:

[image]

Later go to `Instruction/Data` tab and adjust the `Operands`.